# Naming nested variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a few nested blocks:

```
def method123
    my_items.map do |item| 
      item.map do |x|
        if x.is_a?(Array)
          x.map { |x2| ..... } 
        else
          x.to_s.upcase
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I might have done this this way (name all the variables "x") and would work fine as well:

```
def method123
    my_items.map do |x| 
      x.map do |x|
        if x.is_a?(Array)
          x.map { |x| ..... } 
        else
          x.to_s.upcase
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

What is the right way to do this? What's the naming convention for such the cases?

Comment: Which one do you find more understandable?

Comment: What does `item` contain? `x` is not a good name for something that is `Enumerable`. And neither is `x2`. As an example, if `item` has lines, make `x` into `line`. And if a line has characters, make `x2` into `character`. The only time a variable should be named `x` is when it is a coordinate, really. If you have e.g. items including other items, `subitem` and `subsubitem` might be appropriate, but this is stretching it.

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) that recommends best practices so that real-world Ruby programmers can write code that can be maintained by other real-world Ruby programmers.

This is a case of **ShadowingOuterLocalVariable** which is given as a warning if you run [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) which is a Ruby static code analyzer based on Ruby Style Guide.

This is reason first one is preferred

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed it is a correct usage in terms of the Ruby language. So it works fine. But generally you should not do this, at least if your variables don't have the same meaning. In common you don't think that array of objects should be called the same way you call the objects. There are some exceptions I guess, for example when you work with hierarchical structures (like trees), but it is not usual example.

Comment: I didn't get that, could you re-phrase that?